# Is that true, that $f$ is continuous?

Tags: calculus, functions

$ \lim_{h \to 0}(f(x+h)-f(x-h))=0$ ,for every $x \in ℝ$ Is $f$ continuous?

I think that there are counter examples, but I haven't found any until yet.

Comment: hint: Indicator function of $0$

Comment: This limit condition still allows for functions with point discontinuities, as @user251257's comment suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated above in the comments, the indicator function of the set $\{0\}$, $f=\chi_{\{0\}}$, has $\lim_{h\to 0}(f(x+h)-f(x-h))=\lim_{h\to 0}0-0=0$ at every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ but $f$ is obviously discontinuous at $x=0$.